# Why won't justify-content: center move the h2 and #experience_content items to the center of the .experience box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, justify

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.experience {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

}

.experience h2 {
    
}

#experience_content {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="experience">
            
        <h2>Work Experience</h2>
            
        <div id="experience_content">
            <img src=./images/supermarket.jpg width="260" height="195" alt=" shopping center">
                    
        <p> Please help me solve this stupid problem. I beg you.</p>
        </div>

    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried removing the h2 element from the .experience element.

I tried justify-content: center on the #experience_content element, and that didn't work for the img and p elements either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you're applying `justify-content: center` to a flex container with `flex-direction: column`. The `justify-content` property works along the ***[main-axis](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/08/flexbox-alignment/#the-properties)*** of the flex container, which, in this case, is the vertical axis due to `flex-direction: column`. If you want horizontal centering, you'll need to use the property that works on the cross-axis which is `align-items`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .experience {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      /* <-- Here */
    }
    
    .experience h2 {}
    
    #experience_content {
      gap: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="experience">

    <h2>Work Experience</h2>

    <div id="experience_content">
      <img src=./images/supermarket.jpg width="260" height="195" alt=" shopping center">

      <p> Please help me solve this stupid problem. I beg you.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```